# Slack APIを使って、ファイルアップロード時のメッセージにリンクを含める方法を教えてください。

Tags: python, slack

## 環境

- Python 3.11.2
- slack-sdk 3.20.1

## やりたいこと

Slack APIを使って、ファイルアップロード時のメッセージにリンクを含めたいです。

`files.upload` APIの`initial_comment`フィールドに、`<url|text>`形式のテキストを渡しました。

```
In [155]: client=WebClient(os.environ["SLACK_TOKEN"])
In [157]: message=f"<https://qiita.com/|QIITA>"
In [171]: client.files_upload_v2(channel=channel_id, file="README.md", initial_comment=message)
Out[171]: <slack_sdk.web.slack_response.SlackResponse at 0x7f65c8d43250>
```

しかし、リンクにはならず、そのままのテキストが表示されました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

## 質問

ファイルをアップロード時のメッセージに、リンクを含めるにはどうすればよいでしょうか？
Slackアプリでは実現できるので、技術的には可能だと考えています。

## 補足

試したことは以下のブログに書きました。

https://qiita.com/yuji38kwmt/items/67e386750f5950d86e4c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qiita の方にコメントしました。残念ながらワークアラウンドで対応する必要があります： https://qiita.com/yuji38kwmt/items/67e386750f5950d86e4c#comment-3c22a3e7fc249b3a9b18

> こちらは現時点では files_upload_v2 の制約となっており、改善されるか・またその時期は現時点では未定です。
> https://github.com/slackapi/python-slack-sdk/issues/1289
>
> 回避策としては files.upload を使っていただくか、files_upload_v2 を使う場合は initial_comment
> でのメッセージ投稿ではなく、ファイルをアップロードした後にそのファイルの URL を含める形で別途 chat.postMessage
> を呼び出していただくという二つのワークアラウンドがあります。
>
> - https://github.com/slackapi/python-slack-sdk/issues/1289#issuecomment-1300978807
> - https://github.com/slackapi/python-slack-sdk/issues/1194#issuecomment-1076962918